# Serverless not found in docker

Tags: docker, serverless-framework

I'm trying to run serverless in docker.

below are the contents of my local file.

```
FROM node:12.18.4 AS build
COPY . /copy
WORKDIR copy
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
USER node
RUN npm i -g serverless
RUN serverless package
```

I'm getting error

```
Step 7/7 : RUN serverless package
 ---> Running in 2512ef492152
/bin/sh: 1: serverless: not found
```

can you guys please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It might have to do with `USER node` that you have used. remove that and try again

Answer (score 0):

there's brief but dirty solution, removing USER node and adding symbolic link on serverless:

```
FROM node:12.18.4 AS build
COPY . /copy
WORKDIR copy
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
RUN npm i -g serverless
RUN ln -s /home/node/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js /bin/serverless
RUN serverless package
```